# error - Update username in firebase database using ionic v3

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, firebase-authentication

I want to add a username field in firebase, as all said we can't add a direct username field in firebase. I am trying to add via update method. Here I got a code with this if I add value in code that way working but I don't know how can I add value via input.

file.ts

```
this.fAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
  if (user) {
    // Updates the user attributes:
    user.updateProfile({ // <-- Update Method here
      displayName: "Goku",
      photoURL: "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"
    }).then(function () {
      // Profile updated successfully!
      //  "NEW USER NAME"
      var displayName = user.displayName;
      // "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"
      var photoURL = user.photoURL;
    }, function (error) {
      // An error happened.
    });
  }
});
```

file.html

```
<ion-content>
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Username</ion-label>
      <ion-input formControlName="displayName" type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.displayName"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
</form>
</ion-content>
```

please help me...

Comment: Hello, did you try my answer?

Comment: yes, i did but but not solve

Comment: what is the problem? Didn't you want to get the value from html to ts?

Answer (score 0):

To take the value from the html, try the following:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
 <ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Username</ion-label>
    <ion-input formControlName="displayName" type="text" [(ngModel)]="displayName"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <button ion-button type="submit" [disabled]="myForm.invalid">Submit</button>
  </ion-item>
 </ion-list>
</form>
```

Then in the `.ts`, do the following:

```
ngOnInit()
{
 this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  displayName : ['', Validators.required],
 });
}

onSubmit()
{
   if(this.myForm.valid)
   {
     this.displayName = this.myForm.get('displayName').value;
     console.log(this.displayName);
   }
}
```

`this.displayName` will contain the value of the `ion-input`, do not forget to declare the property `displayName` under the class declaration.